# What does "Smell the silent judgement?" mean?

Tags: meaning

In the movie "Avengers: Age of Ultron", Tony Stark says:

> Smell the silent judgement?

to Clint Barton before he tries to lift Thor's hammer. What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

> **[smell](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/smell)** 
> [ T ] informal 
> to know about or **be aware** of a situation without
>   having to be told about it

I don't remember the scene but Tony is asking Clint if he (Clint) can notice that they are judging him (Tony) silently because you have to be **worthy** to wield Mjolnir. I'm not sure who exactly is making the judgement. If there are no more characters in the scene, it may be the hammer itself.